# Sudoku issue when running the program

Tags: python, sudoku

I have an issue with my Sudoku project in the solver part when running the program and I don't know why is it giving me an error. Does anyone know what's the issue with it?

````
def solver(i=0,j=0):
    global matrice
    if matrice[8][8] != 0 :
        for ligne in range(9):
            print (matrice[ligne])
    else:
        if matrice[i][j]!=0 :
            if j==8:
               solver(0,j+1)
            else:
                solver(i,j+1)
        else:
            for chiffre in range(1,10):
                matrice[i][j] = chiffre
                resultat = test(i,j)
                if resultat == True:
                    solver((i+1)%9 , j+1//8)
                else :
                    solver(i,j+1)
            matrice[i][j] = 0 ```
````

Comment: Please paste the entire stack trace of error you got. Any information about the debugging attempts by you which did not work would help ensure people will answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

this is the beginning of the code :

````
          [0,0,3,6,0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,7,0,0,9,0,2,0,0],
          [0,5,0,0,0,7,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0,4,5,7,0,0],
          [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,6,8],
          [0,0,8,5,0,0,0,1,0],
          [0,9,0,0,0,0,4,0,0]]

def test(i,j):
    global matrice
    for row in range(9):
        if matrice[row][j] == matrice [i][j] and row != i :
            return False
    for colonne in range(9):
        if matrice[i][colonne] == matrice[i][j] and colonne != j :
            return False
    for ligne in range ((i//3)*3,(i//3)*3+3):
        for col in range((j//3)*3,(j//3)*3+3):
            if ligne != i and col != j:
                if matrice[ligne][col]==matrice[i][j] : return False
    return True ```
````